# Upper triangular similitude for symplectic matrices

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-group

It is known that given any matrix $M$ in $Sp(2,\mathbb{Z})$ with eigenvalue $+1$, we can find a real symplectic matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}MS$ is upper triangular with diagonal entries equal to $+1$.

In the case of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{Z})$, do we have a similar result ? Any reference or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Normal forms of real matrices under conjugation are determined in Burgoyne & Cushman 1977 - Conjugacy Classes in Linear Groups.

Comment: Thank you @TobiasDiez.